# Access to SQL: IFF function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have not used access before but I have to convert an access query into SQL so I can write a report in crystal.

The query currently uses the IFF function in its select statement which appears to determine what value will be returned depending on the table's value for a particular column.

So for instance if the value is "CR" it should be returned as "credit" and if it's "NCR" it should be returned as "non-credit"

Can I do something like this in SQL?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention it is an oracle DB and am using PL/SQL, if it makes a difference (I am relatively new to DB)

Comment: For future questions, yes it is critical to mention what database backend you are using. PL/SQL is very different from other flavors of SQL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a [CASE](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/case.php) expression.

```
CASE WHEN SomeColumn = 'CR' THEN 'credit'
     WHEN SomeColumn = 'NCR' THEN 'non-credit'
END
```

Comment: But I'd call it a CASE expression, as the CASE statement refers to the PL/SQL statement that ends with "END CASE".

Comment: @Rob: I'll change the terminology.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN [value] = 'CR' THEN 'Credit' WHEN [Value] = 'NCR' THEN 'non-credit' END
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to CASE expressions, Oracle database also supports the DECODE() function.

```
SELECT DECODE(value, 'CR', 'Credit', 'NCR', 'Non-Credit') from table;
```

There are few cases where it may be useful to use a DECODE() function rather than a CASE expression, but I would recommend sticking with CASE.